# No RPi response

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, power

So yesterday I was using my Pi 3 when the power went out. I wasn't really worried, I just unplugged the Pi, turned the power back on, then waited for about 30 minutes, and then turned the Pi back on. And then I wasn't getting ANY response. The green light wasn't flashing, my TV said "No signal detected" and so I thought that I didn't plug in the HDMI properly. So I unplugged it, plugged it, and turned the Pi on (again). Same thing happened, so I decided to install NOOBS again. I deleted all Pi partitions, created a new one, set it as active, formatted the SD card, etc... When I plugged the SD card back in the Pi and turned it on, nothing happened, just the red light turned on (like before).
BTW I already had the newest NOOBS version installed.
What do I do to make it work again?

Comment: What happens if you plug it in with *no* SD card in?  Does the green led then come on?

Comment: No it doesn't. Just the red light turns on.

Comment: I asked because I thought the 3 puts the green led (aka. the "ACT" led, as in "activity", normally referring to the SD card controller) on solid like the 2 when no, or an unusable, card is in it.  But I double checked that and it's not the case, so most likely it is just the card isn't formatted properly.   People seem to have this problem frequently -- the good news is your Pi is probably fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to format my SD card again now with the SD card formatting program. From the moment I turned the Pi on the green light immediately flashed, and it started booting up. Thanks to goldilocks.